# I'm trying to automate update of vmware vsan hcl database using powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, vmware, rest, powercli

When I run Update-VSanHclDatabase I receive the following error:

```
Update-VsanHclDatabase : 6/12/2021 7:09:35 AM    Update-VsanHclDatabase  Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: i    
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-VsanHclDatabase
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-VsanHclDatabase], VimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError,VMware.VimAutomation.Storage.Commands.Cmdlets.Vsan.UpdateVsanHclDatabase
```

I'm using Windows 2012 Server and vSphere version 7.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have used `Connect-VIServer` first? Please add your version of PowerShell and the output of both `Get-Module -Name VMware* -ListAvailable | Select Name,Version` and `$Error[0].Exception.PSObject.Properties | select Name,Value | FL *` immediately after running the failing command  to your post if you still require help.

Comment: Please also update your post with the full command/code you are running or a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the command with powershell 7. It worked fine